# iPhone memory leaking?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios

Really quick question that is driving me INSANE.  I was wondering if someone could tell me why this line is leaking?

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<someXML><tagWithVar=%@></tagWithVar></someXML>",var];
post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"xmlValue=%@",(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                                                               NULL,
                                                                               (CFStringRef)post,
                                                                               NULL,
                                                                               (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                                               kCFStringEncodingUTF8 )];
```

I am just encoding a string into a URL format.  From my understanding, stringWithFormat: should return an autoreleased object.  Apparently that is not the case.  It works, but leaks.  Any ideas??

Comment: FYI, this has nothing to do with Xcode, so I retagged your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are using the method `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`. If a Core Foundation function has "Create" in its name, it means that you own the returned object. In other words, you'll need to release the `CFStringRef` returned by `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`.

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"...", var];
CFStringRef stringRef = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(...);
post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"xmlValue=%@",(NSString *)stringRef];
CFRelease(stringRef);
```

Comment: Only because you were helpfully retagging the question. :)

Comment: It still looks like it is being autoreleased at some point.  When I try to call [post release]; after I set everything up, it crashes when a zombie is called (after I clearly released it myself).

Comment: It is not `post` that needs to be released. It is the `CFStringRef` returned by `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` that needs to be released.

Comment: Can you describe exactly how to do that?  I tried it and it's still leaking.  I even tried extracting the CFStringRef into it's own object:                     CFStringRef *tempRef

Comment: I've updated my answer to include code. Let me know if you're still having problems.

Comment: Awesome.  I think that did the trick.  I was incorrectly releasing it.  (I am still trying to understand the CF functions).  I changed the release to CFRelease(stringRef); and that solved the problem.  Thanks.   :)