# + (NSString *)decodeFromPercentEscapeString:(NSString *)string potential leak

Tags: nsstring, memory-leaks

I got issues when I analyse my code.

Espacially on this methods.

I pucked up this lines on the web. It works well but I got a Portential leak message

**Potential leak on the object. (on the return).**

```
// Encode a string to embed in an URL.    
+ (NSString *)encodeToPercentEscapeString:(NSString*)string {
        return (NSString *)
        CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                (CFStringRef) string,
                                                NULL,
                                                (CFStringRef) @"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    }

    // Decode a percent escape encoded string.
    + (NSString *)decodeFromPercentEscapeString:(NSString *)string {
        return (NSString *)
        CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NULL,
                                                                (CFStringRef) string,
                                                                CFSTR(""),
                                                                kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this post:
[iPhone memory leaking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228348/iphone-memory-leaking)

I have to release the CFString with CFRelease();

```
+ (NSString *)encodeToPercentEscapeString:(NSString*)string {

    CFStringRef str = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                            (CFStringRef) string,
                                            NULL,
                                            (CFStringRef) @"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                            kCFStringEncodingUTF8);


    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)str];
    CFRelease(str);

    return s;
}
```